# Add column from other dataframe on a specific column while keeping original indexes

Tags: pandas, dataframe, join, merge, concatenation

New to Pandas and trying to add a column from `df2` to `df1` based on a column that both of the dataframes have in common. I want to preserve the indexes in `df1`. Notice that `df2` has lots of duplicate rows, including duplicate ItemIds.

```py
DataFrame 1

     ItemId
0    1
1    4
2    7
3    8
```

```py
DataFrame 2

0    column1    ItemId    column_to_merge
1    21984      1         apple
2    89767      1         apple
3    84595      2         pear
4    90876      4         tree
5    59876      5         cookie
6    50758      5         cookie
7    85738      7         monster
8    34980      8         kick
```

Expected outcome

```
DataFrame 1

     ItemId    column_to_merge
0    1         apple
1    4         tree
2    7         monster
3    8         kick
```

I want to preserve the indexes of DataFrame 1 and add the column of DataFrame 2 to DataFrame 1.

Any help is much appreciated.

I dropped duplicates in `df2` before doing the merge as proposed by Karthik Katragadda, so that the merge can be done without including the duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple left merge will do the job for you.

Try this :

```
dataframe_1 = dataframe_1.merge(dataframe_2[['ItemId','column_to_merge']], on = 'ItemId', how = 'left')
```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to mention that my ```df2``` has duplicate rows, which is why my expected result contained heaps of duplicated rows, changing the indexes aswell. I fixed it by dropping duplicates in ```df2``` before doing the merge.